# Python2.7 matplotlibメモリーエラーについて

Tags: python, matplotlib

Pythonを勉強している学生のものです。
http://aidiary.hatenablog.com/entry/20111001/1317441171
こちらのサイトを参考にPythonでスペクトログラムを作成しようと思い試していました。

読み込んだファイルが268mbでどうやらファイルサイズが多くメモリーエラーが出てしまいました。
ttp://d.hatena.ne.jp/cslab/20110907/1315363388
対策を調べていてここに行き着きました。

python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py
220行目に
local = None
を追記
しかしエラーはとれず、、、

Python2.6とはちがうのかと諦めています。
エラーのとり方がありましたら教えてください。

mjy様ありがとうございます。
エラー内容：MemoryError:　　　　　としかでていません
動作環境（OS:win7_64bit、Python2.7及びmatplotlibはexeで簡単に導入できるものを使用）、サイズの小さいファイルではエラーが出ないのか：744kbのwavファイルで試したところエラーは出ませんでした。

local = None 消しておきました

失礼しました
この画像のようなエラーです
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーの内容、動作環境（OS、何ビットか、Pythonやmatplotlibのインストール方法）、matplotlibのbackend（pylab.matplotlib.get_backend()で取得できると思います）、サイズの小さいファイルではエラーが出ないのか、あたりの情報があると解決しやすいかと思います。

Comment: 何をしようとしたときにエラーが出るのでしょうか。ファイルを読み込むとき、スペクトログラムを表示しようとしたとき、それとも、別の処理をしようとした時でしょうか。ちなみに、`local = None` を追記するのはまずそうです。

Comment: 「簡単に導入できるもの」というと matplotlib の backend は TkAgg でしょうか。別の backend で動かすとどうなりますか？ （import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg') を import pylab 以前に入れるなど）

Comment: Ubuntu Linux(64bit) + Python 2.7 で試してみたところ、400 MB超の WAV ファイルでも Memory Error は発生しませんでした(データ読み込み・表示とも問題なし)。もしかして、お使いの PC の空きメモリ容量が少なくなっているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 16 bit sampling, monoral 11025 Hz な WAV ファイル(400MB)を読み込んでいますが、波形を表示した時点で python プロセスの使用メモリ量は 3.2 GB になっています。